# form validation from another controller in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have 2 controllers: btnController and formController. I am trying to submit a Form from another controller action. The problem is that the function in the controller should only be called when the Form Validation is Valid. Right now, if the user tries to submit the form without writing anything, the submit function is called.

How can i fix it?

**My code**

```
<div ng-app='app'>
    <div class='header' ng-controller='btnController'>
        <button ng-click='submit()'>
            Submit Form
        </button>
    </div>

    <div class='container' ng-controller='formController'>
        <h2>Form</h2>
        <form id='myform'>
            <input ng-model='name' placeholder='name' required/>
            <span style="color:red" ng-show="myform.name.$dirty &&      myForm.name.$invalid">
                <span ng-show="myform.name.$error.required">Username is required.</span>
            </span>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>


(function(){
    var app=angular.module('app',[]);
    app.controller('btnController',function($scope){
        $scope.submit=function(){
            angular.element(document.getElementById('myform')).scope().submit();
        }
    });

    app.controller('formController',function($scope){
        scope.name;
        $scope.submit=function(){
            alert($scope.name);
        }
    });
})();
```

Here is the example [JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ajithravindran/u710ze5k/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Edit:**

The submit() function in your 'formController' will only be called when the form is valid:

```
app.controller('btnController',function($scope){
    $scope.submit=function(){
      var elementScope = angular.element(document.getElementById('myform')).scope();
      if(elementScope.myform.name.$valid)
         elementScope.submit();
    }
});
```

**New** **Jsfiddle**: https://jsfiddle.net/oucdodf8/

Comment: that is not my problem. please look at the jsfiddle example

Comment: the submit call was from another controller and not in the form also.

Comment: So you want that the submit() function in your formController will ONLY be called when the form is valid, right?

Comment: Ya right. and also i want to show the validation error

Comment: ya i see that, but it doesn't show the required validation error. thank you

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand what you need.. Where is it supposed to show the required validation error?

Comment: when we click the button without enter anything in the text box, then "Username is required." will show, iam trying to show that text

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/109826/discussion-between-ajith-and-claudio-alves).